# Instaling Web Toolkit(WT) on Windows

Tags: c++, boost, wt

I decided to use [webtoolkit](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/) framework for one of my projects, but I have a hard time to make it work properly.

I was following [this tutorial](http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/projects/wt/wiki/Installing_Wt_on_MS_Windows) but failed few times trying it on Microsoft Visual Studion 2010 and 2008. First time, I was installing on MVS 2010, managed to get hello world app working, but when trying start more advanced examples it failed to do so. This time I tried to do it with MVS 2008, but now it fails to compile at all, giving me errors like:

```
libboost_random-vc90-mt-gd-1_43.lib(random_device.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static bool const boost::random_device::has_fixed_range" (?has_fixed_range@random_device@boost@@2_NB) already defined in wtd.lib(WRandom.obj)
```

My operational system is windows 7.
My actions sequence is all the same as in tutorial I linked above, but at first when I do CMake can't do that to get rid of all red fields but tutorial says:

> 'Configure' again. A few messages about the FCGI and wthttpd connector
>   may pop up; just click Ok. A few new configuration fields (in red)
>   will have popped up; leave them unchanged and press 'Configure' once
>   more. If all went well, you have now no red fields left and the
>   configuration is complete.

but after pointing boost library to correct destination it still seems to have red errors while configuring. When building selected projects it fails with errors I wrote above.

I haven't worked much with additional libraries in C++ before, so maybe I'm missing some key moves to make it happen, if anyone could help, I would be very grateful. I am using boost 1.43 and latest WT version which is 3.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try to toggle the WT_NO_BOOST_RANDOM cmake define - thay may help. There was some talk about this on the wt-interest mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore boost random library by adding below option to your project's linker Command Line(**Project->Properties->Linker-> Command Line**).
 Or You can set to ignore that library in **Project->Properties->Linker->Input->Ignore Specific Default Liraries.**

```
/NODEFAULTLIB:"libboost_random-vc90-mt-gd-1_43.lib"
```